# vertically split panel with draggable handle to adjust panel's height

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface

I'm new to angular. I'm creating vertically split panel with "drag handle" to adjust top and bottom tree panel. I've implemented three stages toggle but I'm not be able to execute dragging of height of the div with mouse event vise-versa. I do not want to use renderer or HostListener or ng-split directive maybe with custom function/method would be nice. can anybody look at my code and help me out. here's what I've done so far.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hm4zy9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to subscribe to [drag event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag), also do not forget to add [draggable="true"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable) to your draggable element. The calculations seem to be correct from the first sight. Check the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdwn7v), I've changed just a bit of your code

Comment: yes I have considered drag event but didn't think it would fit my requirement. though thanks for the suggestion let me see what can be done.

Comment: what's your requirement then?

Comment: my requirement is exactly like any draggable vertically split panel. I did managed to work, but its not in traditional angular way. here take a look at this rough example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hm4zy9

Comment: good, that you worked it out. Still I do not see any reason to not subscribe to drag event and overcomplicate it. But that's up to you